# No response when using jQuery/AJAX with JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am trying to make a cross-domain request using jQuery/AJAX. I have the following code;

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://www.cjihrig.com/development/jsonp/jsonp.php?callback=jsonpCallback&message=Hello",
   crossDomain:true
})
.done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Done : " + msg );
})
.fail(function( msg) {
  alert( "Fail : " + msg);
})
.always(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Always : " + msg );
});
```

The URL http://www.cjihrig.com/development/jsonp/jsonp.php?callback=jsonpCallback&message=Hello returns JSON object when calling directly and works fine when using JSONP in traditional manner (i.e. through dynamic script tag injection)

But why do I get an error when using it with jQuery/AJAX ?

Comment: You need to tell jQuery to use JSONP. http://jsfiddle.net/CttQZ/

Comment: Ok..thx a lot...Does this also not work when testing from local machine ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code because the error isn't set the dataType and isn't expect a jsonp default 
**dataType:** (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
**Type:** String

```
  $.ajax({
   url: "http://www.cjihrig.com/development/jsonp/jsonp.php?callback=jsonpCallback&message=Hello",
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   crossDomain:true,
    jsonp: false,
    success: jsonpCallback,
})
.done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Done : " + msg );
})
.fail(function( msg) {
  alert( "Fail : " + msg);
})
.always(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Always : " + msg );
});

 function jsonpCallback(data){
        alert("jsonpCallback");
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XdSUc/3/)

Comment: Can I optimize the code further like split the URL and have the query string part (thing after ?) in a separate variable ?

Comment: you can use a viariable called params and concatenate it 'http://www.cjihrig.com/development/jsonp/jsonp.php?'+params, @testndtv

Comment: Actually I was asking if it is possible to define the part "callback=jsonpCallback&message=Hello" in a separate AJAX settings variable ? Also my callback function is not getting executed...How do I do that ? like here I have defined function jsonpCallback() ...but it does not get called...

Comment: Ok you can use the param data like this: data: {status: status, name: name}, @testndtv

Comment: Ok..also why does jsonpCallback() not get called after the AJAX request is complete ?

Comment: I think you have to declare It like this type:  jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback', where jsonpCallback is a function @testndtv

Comment: for this problem I have found this question I hope it will be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215235/jsonpcallback-function-not-working @testndtv

Comment: I tried all the solutions listed there...But still does not work...jsonpCallBack: function() { alert('boo'); }

Comment: Is it possible for you to try it out?

Comment: I have update my answer and the jsfiddle with another solution

Comment: So in your example it is the success function which is getting called back and not the jsonpcallback....

Answer (score 0):

I would use $.ajax with the option:

```
dataType: "jsonp"
```

This automatcially adds the callback option to the url. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/