# How get xml result(cross domain request)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, json

I need to make a request to a dedicate website , using jsonp for cross domain reason to get back a XML result and  work on it.
So basicly I am doing this to start :

```
(function($) {
var url = 'http://www.website.....';
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
    url: url,
   // async: false,
   // contentType: "application/json",
dataType: 'jsonp',
});
})(jQuery);
```

I can finally get an answer from website, that I can see in the firebug plugin, but in XML tab
such as :

```
<Results xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.website.com">
<ResultSet id="searchResults" numResults="3" >
```

From my understanding jsonp is a json object and in my case it s returning a XML content.

My problem is how to manage the XML return from the website? I can parse it and play with in the javascript code.

Comment: try adding callback in ajax options

Comment: I don't think `$.ajax` will accept xml in a `jsonp` request. It is basically a script request where the response is a function call. That won't eval xml well I don't think. Suggest you just use a proxy

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Parse XML Cross-domain in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068963/how-to-parse-xml-cross-domain-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your jsonpcallback in order to tinker with the return value of the request.

See:

[jsonpCallback function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215235/jsonpcallback-function-not-working)

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: that link has no bearing on jQuery ajax api